# How to add a simple action button on Wordpress setting from php?

Tags: php, wordpress, settings

Have a custom menu setting using `add_settings_section` and `add_settings_field`, but, how to add a simple action button?. by example, for load a starter example pages for custom blocks of developed theme. The `add_settings_field` function only use the text field but need a action button.